# Failed to get data: this.functionname is not a function (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a function in react's component render method, which I am calling inside return () as shown:

```
render () {
  const Viewperson = () =>{
    return (
      console.log("show perons");
    );
  }
  return (
    {this.Viewperson()}
  );
}
```

I get the following error "Failed to get data: this.Viewperson is not a function"
Can't see where I made mistake. Any suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: You would use just `Viewperson()`, but what is the purpose of such code inside `render`?

Comment: Viewperson is not on the scope of the class its in the scope of the render function. You should make that declaration above the render fn

Comment: Why are you returning the console.log? This is very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` refers to the class instance. The function is inside render, and is not a class method:

```
render () {
  const viewPerson = () => {
    return <div>Person</div>;
  }

  return viewPerson();
}
```

If `viewPerson` was defined inside the class itself, you would use `this`:

```
class Facebook extends Component {

  // ....

  viewPerson() {
    return <div>View Person</div>;
  }

  render() {
    return this.viewPerson();
  }
}
```

Notice that returning `console.log()` will most likely show you an error as you are not returning anything. Just return some **JSX** (`<div>Hi</div>`) if you need to test that it's working.

Also, I reformatted your code a little bit. `camelCase` is used usually used in function or variable declarations, `PascalCase` is usually for Classes or JSX Components. Here are some examples:

```
class ViewPerson() ...

function viewPerson() { return <div>...</div> }
const viewPerson = () => (<div>...</div>)

// A more advanced version:
render() {
  // refers to a Component, so PascalCase 
  const WhichPerson = teacher ? ViewTeacher : ViewStudent;

 // variable holding JSX, so camelCase 
  const person = <WhichPerson>Person details...</WhichPerson>;

  return person;
}
```

This can all be a bit confusing, so don't worry about it too much. You will remember it later on :)

Comment: Thanks alot for detailed explanation...it makes sense now :)

Comment: Glad I could help!